# Make JS string into .html download link

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a JavaScript button that downloads a html page wich is put into a string. 
So that people can download a page for offline viewing.

So I have this string (Just a small sample):

```
var DownloadHtml="<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Test</p></body></html>";
```

And I want to be able to let the user download that HTML page.

Edit on an attempt to make it more clear:

I would prefer something downloadable so the user has it on his desktop. It's not really an offline version of the page itself, it's a timelist of taggings in a video service, the tags are shown in a list while watching, but you could also download it to see who commented when and by clicking on one of the comments you open the video on the time the person had commented

Comment: why not simply telling the user to press `ctrl+s` or `cmd+s` ?

Comment: you can use my download library at http://danml.com/js/download.js to download it; something like download(DownloadHtml, "saved.html", "text/html");

Comment: I don't want the user having to create the html file himself, as not everybody is "smart enough" to create a .html file (You always end with people creating .html.txt files not knowing why)

Comment: @dandavis it looks good I'ma try it out right now

Comment: @dandavis Thanks a lot, is working. Is it also possible to maybe let the user chose the path of where it downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an answer:

```
<script src="http://danml.com/js/download.js">
<script>
  var DownloadHtml="<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Test</p></body></html>";
  download(DownloadHtml, "saved.html", "text/html");
</script>
```

note that if you want to support old browsers, you'll need to echo it off of a server and attach a content-disposition header.

Comment: The page self uses html5 so no need for the older browsers, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cache and `<html manifest=...>`
It allows you to define, what are the elements to be shown while the user is viewing offline.

Read more:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_html_manifest.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: @dandavis If the aim is to download the page at all costs - then you're right.
But if the aim is to let the user view the page offline - my suggestion would help.

Comment: i just didn't see any external resources at all in the OP, so i don't see how the manifest helps. maybe it's not the best question title...

Comment: I would prefer something downloadable so the user has it on his desktop.

It's not really an offline version of the page itself, it's a timelist of taggings in a video service, the tags are shown in a list while watching, but you could also download it to see who commented when and by clicking on one of the comments you open the video on the time the person had commented.

Comment: @Onno Now i got your idea. So, you may not pay attention to my answer =)